# How to get some values from list

Tags: python

I have a converted dict which i got from API and I should get A Name from routes. When I'm trying to get it, I always get first value

I was trying it as it was in one exapmle(I don't search it example , I show it on my code `Namereponsibleroutes = alltext[i]['routes'][0]['name']`) but I have first value, Without it `[0]`, I have a error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

```
alltext=[{'category': {'id': 'd41d97eb-6ecc-4aed-b9be-4fca3411d2c8',
               'name': 'С',
               'vendorId': 'С'},
  'format': {'id': 'fad3d784-6a79-4af8-bf66-db214fadef11',
             'name': 'магазин',
             'vendorId': '1'},
  'freeVisit': False,
  'id': 'fd65865b-0f43-468b-80a5-04d5c9f90086',
  'name': 'магазин-кафетерій',
  'relationships': [{'orderIndex': 1,
                     'relationship': {'deferment': 90,
                                      'id': '44a3297a-37fc-4844-a6ee-43de0a8bfcf3',
                                      'limit': 0.0,
                                      'name': 'Договор № 32207330',
                                      'vendorId': '32207330'}}],
  'routes': [{'dateFrom': '2018-01-01T00:00:00Z',
              'id': '9466dd46-53c8-4ff4-bfaa-0115262eeed9',
              'name': 'string1',
              'vendorId': '154788512'},
             {'dateFrom': '2018-01-01T00:00:00Z',
              'id': 'eac2a7e1-b9c7-4b14-b165-21f5e95bd71f',
              'name': 'string2',
              'orderPricePolicy': {'discountPercentEnabled': False,
                                   'discountPercentFrom': 0.0,
                                   'discountPercentIsFractional': False,
                                   'discountPercentTill': 0.0,
                                   'markupPercentEnabled': False,
                                   'markupPercentFrom': 0.0,
                                   'markupPercentIsFractional': False,
                                   'markupPercentTill': 0.0,
                                   'priceEditEnabled': True}},
             {'dateFrom': '2018-01-01T00:00:00Z',
              'fetchMethod': 'byRelationships',
              'id': 'a2890f23-a1d9-458c-9755-3deed8fc3153',
              'name': 'string3',
              'orderPricePolicy': {'discountPercentEnabled': True,
                                   'discountPercentFrom': 1.1,
                                   'discountPercentIsFractional': True,
                                   'discountPercentTill': 5.5,
                                   'markupPercentEnabled': False,
                                   'markupPercentFrom': 0.0,
                                   'markupPercentIsFractional': False,
                                   'markupPercentTill': 0.0,
                                   'priceEditEnabled': True},
              'refundPricePolicy': {'discountPercentEnabled': False,
                                    'discountPercentFrom': 0.0,
                                    'discountPercentIsFractional': False,
                                    'discountPercentTill': 0.0,
                                    'markupPercentEnabled': True,
                                    'markupPercentFrom': 5.5,
                                    'markupPercentIsFractional': True,
                                    'markupPercentTill': 7.7,
                                    'priceEditEnabled': False}},
             {'dateFrom': '2018-01-01T00:00:00Z',
              'id': '174ead71-d11a-427f-9a15-70dd3606b51e',
              'name': 'string4'},
             {'dateFrom': '2018-01-01T00:00:00Z',
              'fetchMethod': 'byRelationships',
              'id': 'b89975cc-5043-4bb9-9aa5-a2330b217d74',
              'name': '666',
              'vendorId': '666'},
             {'dateFrom': '2018-01-01T00:00:00Z',
              'id': '6bc4381a-b7a1-4c35-98a2-ab58400c8689',
              'name': 'string5'},
             {'dateFrom': '2018-01-01T00:00:00Z',
              'id': 'ee16712c-f63c-492d-a4f5-cc6158f77a4e',
              'name': 'string6',
              'orderPricePolicy': {'discountPercentEnabled': True,
                                   'discountPercentFrom': 10.0,
                                   'discountPercentIsFractional': False,
                                   'discountPercentTill': 30.0,
                                   'markupPercentEnabled': True,
                                   'markupPercentFrom': 40.0,
                                   'markupPercentIsFractional': False,
                                   'markupPercentTill': 70.0,
                                   'priceEditEnabled': True},
              'vendorId': '1050'},
             {'dateFrom': '2018-01-01T00:00:00Z',
              'id': 'bf57c2b6-035f-4c21-b8c2-e102eed032d1',
              'name': 'string7'}],
  'vendorId': '232231'}]


        for i in range(len(alltext)):
            Namereponsibleroutes = alltext[i]['routes']['name']

            print(Namereponsibleroutes)
```

I expect the output of string1, string2, string3, string4, string5, string6, string7, But the actual output is string1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alltext[i]['routes']` is a list of dictionaries. So to get the values of the key `'name'` from each dictionary in the list you have to extract each one. You an do this with a list comprehension

```py
Nameresponsibleroutes = [routeDict['name'] for routeDict in alltext[i]['routes']]
# I am assuming that alltext usually has more than one dictionary in it, otherwise if it is always only 1, change `i` to `0` or don't have it be a list
```